# Date Picker not displaying

Tags: date, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am creating a MS Access 2016 database. In one table it has two date fields and one time field. In the table format, both the date fields are set up with the "show date picker" property set to "for dates". Also, on the forms where these two fields are used, the fields are both set to "for date". The problem is that the date picker is only showing for one, although all properties are identical, other than field name of course. I've adjusted page sizes and field sizes, but nothing seems to help. Has anyone seen this problem before? Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 5):

Whoops! I was mistaken when I said that all the properties for the two date fields were identical. The one field that wasn't showing the date picker had an input mask. As soon as I removed that, the date picker appeared. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

Date pickers and input masks are mutually exclusive. I removed the input mask and the date picker showed up.